# Solving trignometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to solve for $sin(x) = \frac{-1}{2}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$

If I take $ sin^{-1}\frac{-1}{2}$ on my calculator I will get $\frac{-\pi}{6}$  as a solution and then I add $2\pi$ because I know that $sin(x) = sin(x+2\pi)$.  And so I have $\frac{11\pi}{6}$ as a solution. However, How can I get that $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ as another solution ?

I want a very easy way.

Comment: It might help to think about in which quadrants is $\sin(x)$ _negative_.. Also, $\frac{-\pi}{6} = \frac{11\pi}{6}$ (we rotate around the graph counter clockwise).

Comment: sin is negative in 3rd and the 4th quadrant but then what ?

Comment: Then your two solutions are $\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{7\pi}{6}$ and $2\pi - \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{11\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never learn fundas from a calculator! Use a text-book or other standard web resource.

From first to fourth quadrant it is All Silver Tea Cups for positive argument. If argument is negative then reflect the two solution vectors about x_ or y_ axis.

In case of inverse sine stay in

for $ x > 0  $ quadrants $ 1,2  $ and for $ x < 0  $ quadrants $ 3,4. $

If arcsin(1/2) is 30 deg , 150 deg in the former case, it is 210 and 330 (-30) deg for latter.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin(x)=-1/2=-\sin\frac\pi6=\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi6\right)$$

$$\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(-\dfrac\pi6\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

For even $n=2m,x=2m\pi-\dfrac\pi6=\dfrac\pi6(12m-1)$

As $0\le x\le2\pi,0\le\dfrac\pi6(12m-1)\le2\pi\iff0\le12m-1\le12\iff m=1$ as $m$ is an integer

Similarly for  odd $n=2m+1 $

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ and $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$.

If $\sin(-\pi/6)=-1/2$, then we also have $\sin(7\pi/6)=-1/2$ and $\sin(11\pi/6)=-1/2$.